# How to selenium test a website that uses Google OAuth

Tags: selenium, oauth, google-api

I'm building a website that uses Google OAuth to authenticate users and to perform actions in Google (sending emails, creating calendar events, etc.) on the user's behalf.

I want to use selenium to test that the website works as I expect. This includes website specific stuff (e.g. pressing this button causes this entry in the DB), but also Google specific stuff (e.g. pressing this button causes this exact email to be sent).

How do I reasonably test this using selenium? How can I log in automatically? Is there any way at all for me to test that user X can't perform these certain actions but user Y can?

Currently I save a JSONified user record (with Google credentials) in a file and load that file when the tests set up. If the file can't be found then it boots up a browser window and sleeps until I've manually signed in using that browser window. This feels hacky and fragile. It also prevents me from having CI testing because the user record file is only available on my machine.

Answer (score 6):

You could create different accounts allowing different privileges. Then simply automate the login just like a real user would do.
This is a Python example to login to StackOverflow through GMail:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/users/login")

# Click GMail login
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[.='Google']").click()

# type email
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "Email"))).send_keys('...')

# click next
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "next"))).click()

# type password
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "Passwd"))).send_keys('...')

# click signin
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "signIn"))).click()

# wait for the end of the redirection
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "nav-questions")))
```

Comment: Thanks Florent. We're using Google Apps so each extra account would cost us money, it would be nice if there were a way of doing it without paying more. I'm also personally using 2FA so I can't automate my own login.

Comment: You should disable the 2FA since the authentication process is not handled by your app.

Comment: Sorry I meant that I have 2FA enabled for my Google account. So the sign in using Google process involves providing the 2FA token, something I cannot automate.

Comment: 2FA is not a token, it means "Two Factor Authentication" and is labelled as "2-Step Verification" in GMail. You can easily disable it in the settings.
This example automates the login for a 1 step authentication with Gmail / OAuth2.

Comment: I think we might be misunderstanding each other. When I sign into my Google account (regardless of this website) I'm asked for my email address, my password, and a time-limited token provided to me by my 2FA device. It helps secure my account so I'm not going to disable it for the purposes of these tests.

Comment: I understand. My point is that you should disable the 2FA if you want to automate the login. Having a 2FA has no purpose here. If you are concerned with the security then you should work with a GMail account tailored for the purpose of your tests.

Comment: As @FlorentB. was saying, the correct method is to set up specific test accounts. There are a variety of reasons why using a real user account for general testing is not a good idea. One of which, as you've discovered, is potentially wanting to use 2FA on your normal user account.


The best method, if you don't want to use up G Suite licenses, is to simply create normal, free Gmail accounts for the test users. I'm assuming this is probably against the Google ToS somehow, but shouldn't actually cause any issues if you're not overusing them.

Comment: Eventually You will get trapped with google verification.